# custom CellRenderer lose it's style when embeded in the TileList

Tags: actionscript-3

I have defined a renderer with some Labels, TextInputs and Buttons and call "setStyle" to set their colors and font when i create it.

If i add the renderer in some normal panels, the style works fine.

If i put it in a TileList object, the style will be lost

code like this:

```
    public class MyRenderer extends UIComponent implements ICellRenderer
    {
        public function MyRenderer()
        {
            private var m_label = new Label();
            m_label.setStyle("textFormat", someTextFormat);
            addChild(m_label);
        }
    }

    var m_tileList:TileList = new TileList();
    m_tileList.setStyle("cellRenderer", MyRenderer)
    m_tileList.addItem({});//the renderer showed but the "someTextFormat" lose
```

Comment: i've solved it by using drawNow() after i create the label

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely more difficult finding information on how to use the fl.controls components since Adobe came out with CS 6. The information on how to use stules with them is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f5b.html).

Try something like

```
StyleManager.setComponentStyle(MyRenderer, "textFormat", someTextFormat);
```